# Set a default overlay color for the Core Cover block in theme.json

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing, theme.json

I would like to know if it is possible to set a default Overlay color for the Core Cover block using theme.json, so that when a new Cover block is added, that Overlay color is pre-set rather than having no color selected.

I know you can create a custom palette for the Cover block like so:

```
"settings": {
    "blocks": {
        "core/cover": {
            "color": {
                "palette": [
                    {
                        "color": "#ffffff",
                        "name": "White",
                        "slug": "white"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this just restricts the color palette - it does not set a color when a new Cover block is added to the Editor.

Comment: Not yet possible to automatically set the color by default (https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/27809).

Comment: @Will If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it. Disappointing, but a solid answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not yet possible. This has been requested at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/27809 and if you have a github account, you can subscribe to the issue and keep track of its progress.